# how to save JSON data in session by using Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I want to save json object data to the session in Laravel. but I failed to save anything and it returns null when called.
see codes below

```
 public function CustomerLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);
    if (Auth::guard('customer')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {
        $datas = collect(array(Auth::guard('customer')->user()));
        session()->put('key',$datas);
        return "success";
    }else{
        return "false";
    }
}
public function getProfile(Request $request){
    $data = $request->session()->get('key');
    return response()->json(["profile"=>$data]);
```

}

I want to save returned JSON data from DB and save in session then retrieve session data from getprofile function.
it only return token

Comment: Can you show where/how you're retrieving the from the session?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $request->session()->put('key',$datas);
```

you dont need double quotes

Also, you can use the global session helper function like this

```
$data = session()->put('key',$datas);
```

But I don't see where you retrieve the session back